# Wrong vertical distance between last paragraph of a letter and the closing with setspace

Tags: spacing, line-spacing, letters, setspace, vertical-spacing

I'm using the `letter` class together with the `setspace` package with `doublespacing` option. Also, I set a 2 em paragraph indent an a 0 pt paragraph skip. The matter is that I don't get double-spacing between the last paragraph and the closing of the letter. A minimal working example.

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{letter}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}

\signature{Me}
\def\fromaddress{\null}
\date{Here, today}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{}
\opening{Dear Somebody:}    
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt plus 0.1pt}
        
Content of the letter.

\closing{Greetings,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Here is a screenshot of the result I get
[image: Screenshot]

I tried to solve the problem with `\vspace{\baselineskip}`, but I didn't get the proper spacing.

Comment: This is not directly related to `setspace`: `\closing` does a vertical space of `\parskip`  which you have set to be 0pt by default, with just a small amount of stretch, which is not used here anyway`  You could patch the command but simplest would be simply to put `\vspace{20pt}` before \closing`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle How do you compute the 20pt? This is a MWE, so I will need different spacing for different fonts and sizes. For example, now I'm using Adobe Garamond Pro scaled by 1.25 at 12pt.

Comment: I just made it up, it's a letter not a scientific calculation, just pick a value that looks right to you.  you can make it follow the font size by using something like `2em` or `2\baselineskip` rather than a fixed value like `20pt`

Comment: why double space a letter anyway?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well, I'm a bit obsessive with this kind of things, that's why I use LaTeX for writing even letters; but I get your point. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I like my letters with a lot of white space

Comment: it's your readers who have to suffer the consequences though.

Comment: I didn't know about that consequences. I will read about. Thanks

Comment: it is definitely harder to read text that is so spaced you have to adjust your eyes to scan to pick up the next line. Theses were done that way to allow comments and corrections without having to reprint not to improve readability

Comment: And to fill pages with the half of the content.